# Purely ajax MVC 4 Authentication

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I'm building a single page application using MVC 4. For Log in functionality I do a jquery ajax POST to this action:

```
    [HttpPost] [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult JsonLogin(LogInFormViewModel form)
    {
         ...

         //If user authenticates
            formAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.HttpContext,
                                                 UserAuthenticationTicketBuilder.CreateAuthenticationTicket(
                                                                 user));
            return Json(new { success = true, viewResult = this.RenderPartialView("UserStatusBar", null) });

         ...

    }
```

`RenderPartialView()` is a custom extension that just renders my razor partial view to a string.

The "UserStatusBar" is the standard bar at the top of any website that either says Login/Register if user is not authenticated or Logoff/Welcome if they are:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div id="LoggedIn">
        <a class="logoutLink" href="#">Log out</a>
        <span>Welcome, @User.Identity.Name</span>
    </div>
} else {
    <div id="notLoggedIn">
        <a class="loginLink popupLink" href="#">Log in</a>
        <a class="registerLink popupLink" href="#">Register</a>
    </div>
}
```

In my ajax success handler I do something like this to asynchronously re-render just the user status bar after the user logs in or off:

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
       $('#userStatusBar').empty().html(result.viewResult, null);
    }
}
```

The only problem is, whenever the code steps into my custom extension `RenderPartialView()`, `Request.IsAuthenticated` is still the same as prior to the ajax call, so it wont re-render the correct status bar until the next request.

How can I get around this since `Request.IsAuthenticated` is readonly I cannot simply set it after setting the authorization cookie. The only thing I can do is instead set a TempData property and check that instead when rendering the UserStatusBar:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated || (TempData["AjaxAuthenticated"] != null && (bool)TempData["AjaxAuthenticated"]))
{
    <logged in html>
} else <logged out html>
```

But this is problematic because the reverse happens when logging off; `Request.IsAuthenticated` is STILL true after `formsAuthentication.SignOut()` when the status bar is being re-rendered and it again renders the incorrect markup for the status bar until the next request.

I can't seem to think of a way to get around this because I also need permalinks to work so Request.IsAuthenticated is the one I'd be looking at in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found my answer. I wrote a controller extension that renews the security principal for the current request based on the cookie in current response (set after successful authorization and right before call to this method). This updates `Request.IsAuthenticated` true immediately.

NOTE: I'm using custom membership so this code will not work for you in verbatim.

```
    public static void AjaxRenewPrincipal(this Controller controller)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = controller.HttpContext.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (IsValidAuthCookie(authCookie))
        {
            var formsAuthentication = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IFormsAuthentication>();
            var authTicket = formsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            CustomUser user = new CustomUser(authTicket); //An authenticated user
            string[] userRoles = { user.RoleName };
            controller.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(user , userRoles);
            formsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(controller.HttpContext, authTicket);
        }
        else
        {
            //using Parameter-less constructor on my CustomClass : IIdentity sets IsAuthenticated to false on the IIdentity, then unauthenticated user gets set to the security principal
            controller.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new CustomUser (), new string[] {});
        }
    }
```